# Unable to create docker image in intellij

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, intellij-idea, docker-image

I am trying to containerize one application using docker. But getting java.lang.NullPointerException while running the dockerfile. Can anyone please help in resolving it?

[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yaHCV.png)

### **Helloworld.java**

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello, World!");
    }
}
```

### **Dockerfile**

```
FROM amazoncorretto:11.0.14
COPY ./out/production/DockerHelloWorld/ /tmp
WORKDIR /tmp
ENTRYPOINT ["java","HelloWorld"]
```

[Response while running the dockerfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzuUl.png)

I am trying to follow below link [https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/dockerize-java-app.html#run_java_app_in_container][Dockerize a java application](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/dockerize-java-app.html#run_java_app_in_container)

Comment: Please upload your project at https://uploads.jetbrains.com and share the UploadID here. I've checked the guide above from my side and it worked fine. Ensure the you completed all the steps from the guide